# Pinned SliverPersistentHeader overlaps with Android StatusBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I'm working with Slivers. I have an SliverAppBar, then a SliverPersistentHeader and finally a SliverList.

The behavior I want to achieve is that the SliverAppBar scrolls off the screen but the SliverPersistentHeader to remain pinned at the top of the screen.

I am able to do that but the SliverPersistentHeader overlaps with the android status bar. Any idea on how can I fix this?

[image]
[image]

Finally this is the code

```
class ExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
          pinned: false,
          floating: true,
          snap: true,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
            child: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0), 
            child: Container(
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0, horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('SliverPersistentHeader', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
          ),
        ),
        SliverFixedExtentList(
        itemExtent: 150.0,
        delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
          [
            Container(color: Colors.red),
            Container(color: Colors.purple),
            Container(color: Colors.green),
            Container(color: Colors.orange),
            Container(color: Colors.yellow),
            Container(color: Colors.pink),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final PreferredSize child;

  _SliverAppBarDelegate({ this.child });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return child;
  }

  @override
  // TODO: implement maxExtent
  double get maxExtent => child.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  // TODO: implement minExtent
  double get minExtent => child.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    // TODO: implement shouldRebuild
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I've got a rough workaround but involves using a `Stack` to show a coloured `Container` with the height of the status bar behind a the scroll view wrapped in a `SafeArea`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just wrap your `CustomScrollView` into `SafeArea` :

```
 return SafeArea(
      child: CustomScrollView(
             ...
```

Comment: Apparently, SafeArea doesnt work with SliverPersistentHeader.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you may need to hold your scroll widgets with an scaffold:

```
return Scaffold(
           body: SafeArea(
                 child: CustomScrollView...
```

Comment: Can you [edit] and explain what this answer is doing and how it differs from the other one submitted several years ago?